# Create new Stata variable based on value that might be present in multiple other variables

Tags: variables, stata

Need to create a new binary variable in Stata based on the entries that might appear in 1 of 5 "Response"  variables.

Example of existing data:

```
Resp1 Resp2 Resp3 Resp4 Resp5

A57 A510 B899 Z781 Q56883

A110 A4589 B11345 Z570 D444

A510 B899 Z4721 Z33 M406

B890 B678 T4487 A57 T112

A57 T112 B890 M119 Z4001
```

What I'm trying to do is:

```
generate byte A57_Response = 0
replace A57_Response = 1 if Resp1 == "A57" & substr(Resp1, 3, 1) != "2" 

replace A57_Response = 1 if Resp2 == "A57" & substr(Resp2, 3, 1) != "2" 

replace A57_Response = 1 if Resp3 == "A57" & substr(Resp3, 3, 1) != "2" 

replace A57_Response = 1 if Resp4 == "A57" & substr(Resp4, 3, 1) != "2" 

replace A57_Response = 1 if Resp5 == "A57" & substr(Resp5, 3, 1) != "2"
```

Is there a way to search all 5 Resp variables at once?

Also, is there a way to `generate` a `1` for the new binary variable without writing out the entire response? For example, assign a `1` every time there is a `Z` code, even if it's `Z33`, `Z4001`, or any other possible code that starts with `Z`? Since I'm using the `" "` I know it's currently looking for an exact case match, but is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a string variable is equal to `"A57"` then the condition that its third character isn't `"2"` is redundant: its third character is always `"7"`.

The code is now just

```
 gen wanted = inlist("A57", Resp1, Resp2, Resp3, Resp4, Resp5)
```

The condition that one of those variables starts with `"Z"` is

```
 gen desired = 0 
 forval j = 1/5 { 
     replace desired = 1 if substr(Resp`j', 1, 1) == "Z" 
 }
```

The second problem doesn't require a loop as it too could be written as a calculation using `inlist()`.

EDIT  In your examples `Z` never occurs as a second or later character, so testing for any occurrence of `Z` does not risk false positives:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str7 Resp1 str5 Resp2 str8 Resp3 str5 Resp4 str6 Resp5
"A57"  "A510"  "B899"   "Z781" "Q56883"
"A110" "A4589" "B11345" "Z570" "D444"  
"A510" "B899"  "Z4721"  "Z33"  "M406"  
"B890" "B678"  "T4487"  "A57"  "T112"  
"A57"  "T112"  "B890"   "M119" "Z4001" 
end

egen Resp = concat(Resp?), p(" ")
  
gen wanted = strpos(Resp, "Z") > 0

list 

     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | Resp1   Resp2    Resp3   Resp4    Resp5                          Resp   wanted |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |   A57    A510     B899    Z781   Q56883     A57 A510 B899 Z781 Q56883        1 |
  2. |  A110   A4589   B11345    Z570     D444   A110 A4589 B11345 Z570 D444        1 |
  3. |  A510    B899    Z4721     Z33     M406      A510 B899 Z4721 Z33 M406        1 |
  4. |  B890    B678    T4487     A57     T112      B890 B678 T4487 A57 T112        0 |
  5. |   A57    T112     B890    M119    Z4001      A57 T112 B890 M119 Z4001        1 |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I'm very, very new at this, so may I request a clarification, please. If I wanted to identify the "Q56" as the first three values of any entry, would that then be substr(Resp'j',1,2,3,1) == "Q56" ?

Comment: No. Look at the `help` for `substr()`. That's illegal. There are always three arguments to `substr()`.